# como atribuir valor a uma variável com valores existente em uma variável usando loop Javascript

Tags: array, funções, loop

Usando uma função preciso que uma variável receba valores de uma outra variável (que trata-se de uma lista), um caractere de cada vez e em seguida compare tal resultado com uma variável que recebera dados de um input, dessa forma a intenção e checar se um determido caracter existe ou não na string atribuída pelo input em seguida retorne a informação em tag separadas quando o valor obtido do input tenha apenas números e quando houver a presença de caracter da listastr.
O problema obtido e quando digito algo no input que tem a combinação de números e letras o código retorna o resultado nos elementos de saída.

```js
        function resultado() {

            var dados = document.getElementById('entrada').value;
            //console.log(dados)

            var listastr = 'abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxzwy';
            
            for (let caracter of listastr){
                let filtro = dados.includes(caracter)

                if (filtro==true){
                    document.getElementById('letras').innerHTML='valor da string: '+dados;
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('numero').innerHTML='valor do int: '+dados;
                };
            }
            //console.log('caracter capturado da lista: '+caracter)
        }
```

```html
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="digite um valor" id="entrada">
        <button type="button" onclick="resultado()">Resultado</button>
    </form>

    <div>
        <p>Saida resultado que a presença de letras e números</p>
        <p id="letras"></p>

        <p>Saida resultados somente números</p>
        <p id="numero"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais claro com o que pretende?

Comment: a variável FILTRO serve pra checar se o que o usuário digita no input contém somente números ou se contém números com outros tipos de caracteres. A intenção é retorna essa informação em um dos id dentro da tag <p>.

Comment: Você pode tentar substituir o loop `for ... of` por um simples `for` acessando cada caractere do índice em conjunto com a função `isNaN` (a qual verifica se cada caractere é ou não um número) e ir acumulando cada caractere em duas variáveis, como por exemplo  `var letras` e  `var numeros`. Eu também nao utilizaria a variavel `listastr`.

Comment: Vou deixar um fiddle de exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/0bw6r58g/

Comment: opa ajudou , não era exatamente isso, mas entendi e ja sei o que fazer. 
queria que quando digitasse algo do tipo "teste12345" , toda esta informação fosse para <p id="letras"> E quando digitasse apenas números preenchia o <p id="numero">

Comment: Nesse caso `letras = dados;`

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja verificar se a sua variável contém apenas números. Para isso, você pode utilizar expressões regulares. [Expressões Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions)

Abaixo, segue uma função que pode ajudar:

```
function possuiApenasNumeros(str) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(str);
}
```

- A função `possuiApenasNumeros` recebe uma string str como argumento.
- `return /^\d+$/.test(str);`: Esta linha utiliza uma expressão regular
  com o método `test()` para verificar se a `string str` contém apenas
  números e retorna o resultado.
- `test(str)`:E o metodo que testa se a expressão regular corresponde à
  string str.

O resultado da expressão `^\d+$` será `true` apenas se a string consistir exclusivamente de caracteres numéricos.

Talvez expressões regulares sejam um tópico novo para você. Então, eu sugiro que você dê uma olhada no link que eu compartilhei. Assim, você conseguirá entender o que cada caractere da expressão faz.